# Angular 2, dynamic bind attribute name

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a code block angular 2 like that:

```
<div *ngFor="let elm of elms; let i = index" [attr.name]="name" text-center>
    {{elm }}
</div>
```

It works fine. 
But when i want to dynamic set attribute name base on index like `name-1="name"` `name-2="name"`i dont know how to do it.
I tried `[attr.name-{{i}}]="name"`or `[attr.name- + i]="name"` but it does not work. Is there any way to do it? 
Many thanks.

Comment: how does the resulting html look like?  `<div name1="name"...`?

Comment: @Maximus, `<div name-1="name"...` `<div name-2="name"...`

Comment: @VladimirZdenek, Sorry, it does not work

Comment: Can you please be more specific of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Certainly you can create an `attribute directive` for this.

Comment: @Abrar, I want the html like `<div name-1="name"...` `<div name-2="name"...`. The number 1,2 base on the index `i`

Comment: @AmitChigadani: Yeah, `attribute directive` is cool. But it does not help in this case.

Comment: @Duannx check the soln. Hope it helps to achieve what you need!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To start off thanks to ***OP*** for the question. I eventually learnt new things by solving this answer. Below explanation on how i achieved.

---

**Important:** One catch you cannot bind the **dynamic attribute** to your component **scope**. To achieve this you need to make each *div* as a dynamic component and compile it. Kinda hacky i guess.

---

**Template:**

```
<div #looped *ngFor="let elm of elms; let i = index;" text-center>
  {{elm }}
</div>
```

and in the component import  implements **[AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)** and **[ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)** decorator to get children elements and its changes on rendering:

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
```

**component:**

```
export class ExamplePage implements AfterViewInit {
  elms : Array<string> = ["d1", "d2", "d3"]
  @ViewChildren('looped') things: QueryList<any>;
  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.things.forEach((t, index) => {
      let el : HTMLDivElement = t.nativeElement;
      el.setAttribute("name-" + index , "dynamicAttrString");
    })
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: wow. It is cool. i will check it soon and acept your answer. Thanks

Comment: It works. I accepted it. But there are some points i don't understand.
1. Why need to implement `AfterViewInit`?
2. If place code in `ngAfterViewInit`, it only work when the data is ready in start time. To apply code in anychange, i use ngAfterViewChecked instead. But there is a problem that ngAfterViewChecked fire so many time in one change and it will make my app slower. What i should to do? Thank you

Comment: @Duannx in that case separate the logic in the form of a function and call on ngChange of that particular model.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know weather it is possible or not but I've alternate solution

```
<div *ngFor="let elm of elms; let i = index" [attr.name]="{id : index, data : name}">{{item}}</div>
```

then you'll get object as avalue with **id** and **data** keys, hope this helps.

Comment: It is just a walk around. I just want to know have or not anyway to solve the main problem. Thanks.